# How can I find all values greater then 3, increment them by 1, and append a column of ones in a single line?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to simplify this task to a one-line command, but I just cannot figure out how it should be done. I tried everything that came to my mind without success. My code right now is:

```
A_temp = A;
A_temp(A_temp > 3) = A_temp(A_temp > 3) + 1;
A_final = A_temp;
A_final(:,end+1) = 1;
```

Comment: Why do you create those copies? You basically have only two lines of code (if you don't copy the arrays) I don't see the point in reducing that to one line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will achieve the same result as your above code:

```
A_final = [A+(A > 3) ones(size(A, 2), 1)];
```

Comment: Oh, so probably the + made it, that something new to me. Thank you